# How do I access the Router through an artisan command?

Tags: php, laravel

I need access to the RouteCollection that Laravel possesses when it gets ran normally and all ServiceProviders are booted. I need the RouteCollection because a legacy app needs to know if Laravel has the particular route, so if it doesn't, legacy code can take care of the route.

I figure if I can somehow get a hold of `Illuminate\Routing\Router` in an artisan command, I could simply call the `getRoutes()` function and output a JSON file containing an array of all the routes. Then when the legacy code needs to determine if Laravel supports the Route, it could read that file.

In order to do that though, I need access to the Router class. Not sure how to accomplish that... I looked at `Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RoutesCommand` source code and I can't figure out how it works. What's really odd is it looks like the Router class is being injected, but when I do `Artisan::resolve('MyCommand')`, I get an empty RouteCollection.

**EDIT**

I never did figure out how to accomplish this question, but for those in a similar situation, I found this works for the most part, although I'm not sure how bad the overhead is starting Laravel each request just to check the routes. Right now it doesn't seem like that much.

```
// Start laravel, so we can see if it should handle the request
require_once(__DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php');
$app = require_once(__DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/start.php');
$app->boot();

// Create the fake request for laravel router
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$request->server->set('PHP_SELF', '/laravel/public/index.php/'.$_REQUEST['modname']);
$request->server->set('SCRIPT_NAME', '/laravel/public/index.php');
$request->server->set('SCRIPT_FILENAME', __DIR__.'/laravel/public/index.php');
$request->server->set('REQUEST_URI', '/laravel/public/'.$_REQUEST['modname']);

$routes = Route::getRoutes();

foreach($routes as $route) {
    if ($route->matches($request)) {
        $app->run($request);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean `artisan routes`? To get all list of command check `artisan list`

Comment: `artisan routes` almost does what I want, but not entirely, that is why I'm trying to build a custom artisan command based on it. My goal is to generate a JSON file which non-laravel code could parse and detect if Laravel can handle a given route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified implementation

JsonRoutes.php

```php
<?php
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;

class JsonRoutes extends Command {
    protected $name = 'routes:json';
    protected $description = 'Spits route information in JSON format.';

    protected $router;
    protected $routes;

    public function __construct(Router $router) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->routes = $router->getRoutes();
    }

    public function fire() {
        $result = [];
        foreach ($this->routes as $route) {
            $result[] = [
                'methods' => implode(',', $route->methods()),
                'host' => $route->domain(),
                'uri' => $route->uri(),
                'name' => $route->getName(),
                'action' => $route->getActionName(),
            ];
        }

        $file = $this->option('file');
        if ($file) {
            File::put($file, json_encode($result));
            return;
        }
        $this->info(json_encode($result));
    }

    protected function getArguments() { return []; }

    protected function getOptions() {
        return [
            ['file', 'f', InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'File name.'],
        ];
    }
}
```

You register it in `artisan.php`:

```
Artisan::resolve('JsonRoutes');
```

Sample usage:

Spit it out to stdout

```
$ artisan routes:json
[{"methods":"GET,HEAD","host":null,"uri":"\/","name":null,"action":"Closure"}]
```

Write it to a file

```
$ artisan routes:json -f /tmp/routes.json
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks dude :D. I had a somewhat similar solution, not sure what happen there :P Must of messed something up in my branch.